# How to turn off Thunderbird message "Thunderbird now has calendaring functionality..."

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, lightning

Since installing Ubuntu Mate 16.10, I've been getting the following message at the bottom of Thunderbird's window: "Thunderbird now contains calendaring functionality by integrating the Lightning extension." There are 3 buttons available: Learn more, Disable, Keep. Well, I don't want to disable the Calendar, but whichever button I push, the message keeps coming back. Any idea how to turn this message off without disabling the calendar?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to edit-> preferences->Config Editor and make sure mail . biff . show_balloon  is set to zero. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>edit</kbd>--><kbd>preferences</kbd>--><kbd>Config Editor</kbd> and set  `mail.biff.show_balloon` to zero. This one disable all the popups.